# How do I set RAW+JPEG recording on my Panasonic Lumix GX85?

Tags: camera-settings, panasonic-lumix, raw-plus-jpeg

I am trying to find on the Custom menu RAW+JPEG setting, but I cannot find it. How do I set RAW+JPEG on my Panasonic Lumix GX85?

Answer (score 3):

In the [Panasonic GX85 user manual](https://eww.pavc.panasonic.co.jp/dscoi/DMC-GX85/P_PP/guideUSA.pdf), page 193:

In the `MENU` → `[REC]` → `[Quality]` menu, select RAW + JPEG (it looks like `RAW` next to a stack of 3 or 6 boxes).

[image]

Comment: Or press the button for "Q.Menu", then scroll along to the option for Quality.